# SSLv3 error connecting JDBC to Sql Server 2012?

Tags: java, sql-server, ssl, jdbc

I've switched computers and installed mssql 2012sp2. (latest and greatest Win7 SP, sql server sp, etc)

When running sql via our ant scripts, I (surprisingly) had SSL handshake problems, with this error:

> SSLv3 SSLContext not available

I'm using IBM JDK 1.6 and Microsoft's 2.0 jdbc driver from this file `sqljdbc_2.0.1803.100_enu.tar.gz`

**Some data points**

- MSSQL jdbc drivers use SSL for login
- We have production instances--using the same jdbc drivers--- pointing to MSSQL 2012. I had never seen this problem before.
- I tried `-Dhttps.protocols="TLS"` without any success.

**Some questions**

- Is this a post-POODLE change to MSSQL? Perhaps in a service pack?
- Any workarounds?

thanks

Updated: Clarified I'm using IBM jdk, not Oracle's

Answer (score 1):

The JDK version proved the cause--not sql server. I used a later version of the IBM JDK 1.6 on my new machine.

Specifically the later version of the IBM JDK disables SSLv3 by default.

**Workaround**

Add this option to the JVM

> ```
> -Dcom.ibm.jsse2.disableSSLv3=false
> ```

**Reference**

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21688165#issues

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to examine the SSL  configuration of the SQL  server you are attempting to contact, and make sure it is accepting TLS connections.

The SQL JDBC driver can also be in issue, as some older versions do not play
well with Java 1.7.