# SSLv3 Related Errors - Spring + Hibernate + SQL Server on Tomcat

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, sslv3

I am getting issues connecting to SQL Server 2008 from Spring Hibernate Application hosted on tomcat (RHEL)

My beans :

```
<beans:bean id="sDataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://abc.com:1433;databaseName=ABC;" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="AAAAAAA" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="XXXXXXXX" />
    </beans:bean>
```

Initially I got this error :

```
[04-18-2016 17:45:01,837-0400] [Line:   ?] DEBUG [com.services.hibernate.SessionHandler] [Entering Method getSession()]
[04-18-2016 17:45:01,882-0400] [Line:   ?] DEBUG [com.services.hibernate.SessionHandler] [Exiting Method getSession()]
[04-18-2016 17:45:01,901-0400] [Line:   ?] ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] [The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SSLv3 SSLContext not available".]
[04-18-2016 17:45:01,902-0400] [Line:   ?] DEBUG [com.services.hibernate.SessionHandler] [Entering Method returnSession()]
[04-18-2016 17:45:01,903-0400] [Line:   ?] DEBUG [com.services.hibernate.SessionHandler] [Exiting Method returnSession()]
```

Then I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733799/sslv3-error-connecting-jdbc-to-sql-server-2012), and made changes as `-Dcom.ibm.jsse2.disableSSLv3=false`

And then I got this error:

```
[04-18-2016 17:47:45,728-0400] [Line:   ?] DEBUG [com.services.hibernate.SessionHandler] [Entering Method getSession()]
[04-18-2016 17:47:45,815-0400] [Line:   ?] DEBUG [com.services.hibernate.SessionHandler] [Exiting Method getSession()]
[04-18-2016 17:47:45,845-0400] [Line:   ?] ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] [The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)".]
[04-18-2016 17:47:45,847-0400] [Line:   ?] DEBUG [com.services.hibernate.SessionHandler] [Entering Method returnSession()]
[04-18-2016 17:47:45,848-0400] [Line:   ?] DEBUG [com.services.hibernate.SessionHandler] [Exiting Method returnSession()]
```

The code is completely functioning as it is returning results on my local environment but as I deploy it in cloud (RHEL V6) I am getting these errors.

Please help me out. I am completely stuck at this point.

**Do I need to install something on Linux Server?**

Answer (score 0):

Compare the version of Java.  I ran into an issue around Java8 build 50 where certain ciphers were deprecated and removed, so our application suddenly couldn't establish an SSL connection because the two sides couldn't agree on a cipher to use.  To me this looks similar.

It's also probably worth checking to see if unlimited strength encryption is installed on your desktop but not the server.

Out of desperation, you might try running the app with -Djavax.net.debug=ALL or something else (depends how much detail you need), [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) is a starting point to work with.  You'll have to add it to tomcat.conf (or wherever the environment vars are in your release).